# I need to move the background color, gray, down to cover the length of the page regardless of window size

Tags: php, html, css

I made a comment section for my website and I have a button that allows you to edit your comment which reroutes you to another page.  I have a margin set up so content doesn't get hidden behind my header or footer but now I can't seem to find a way to get the background color to stretch across to the very bottom of the page.

I messed around with the position in css and the background color did stretch to the bottom of the page, but then my header disappeared.

My CSS...

```
#headerContainer {
    margin: -60px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-color:#333;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
.editCommentBody {
    margin: 60px 0px 40px 0px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

The editCommentBody class is everything from the header to the edit button.
[image: website]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not set a value for the fixed position in your headerContainer style . 
try giving left:value and top:value for it and also , when you use positions , margins wont work sometimes , if your margin even works , it has a top:-60px which cause your header to be out of screen , try this :

```
    #headerContainer {
    margin:0px;
    background-color:#333;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}
```

Comment: This helped me alot :D Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the desired background color to the body instead, like this:

`body { color: #ddd; }`

Comment: This may need to be another post entirely but what is the point of using the body tag instead of a div tag with a specific class?  I've just been using div tags, I don't even have a body tag, what am I missing out on?

Comment: Your HTML document should be in this base format            `     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
Content of the document......
</body>

</html>`

Comment: So I'd expect it to have a body tag, even if you're injecting the HTML using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: I tried that in the editcommentbody tag and it didnt work :(

Comment: @AdamJones Well upon reading the question again. If the only problem is the background not stretching, why not give the background property to a wrapping container, the body itself for example if nothing else is in the page.